# How to hide TActionMainMenuBar images

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl

I have `TActionMainMenuBar` placed on the form, which looks like this:

[image: ActionMainMenuBar]

Now, it looks perfectly fine except that blank gap on the left where images should go. Since I don't have need to draw images in the menu, how can I hide that gap completely? Haven't been able to find any properties which I can use to hide this, and Google queries returned no results on the topic.

Comment: I don't think you can hide that gutter. It is used for more than images too. Checks and bullets.

Comment: I'd like to atleast OwnerDraw it if possible, so I can manually determine how it should look. I have need for checks, but it is just too big for that feature, I'd like to shrink it down a bit if possible. Or maybe completely hide it for items that arent checkable, that would be ideal.

Comment: If you need checks then you should just leave it. Your users won't care. You could write your own style hook but it's easy to get them wrong.

Comment: Open Notepad on your computer and look at its menu. That's what standard Windows menus look like. There's a gutter there whether there are images or not.

Comment: But standard menu gutter is alot smaller in width and also delimiter line goes all the way to the beggining. While in TActionMainMenuBar it doesn't. Looks just ugly starting from 1/5th of the whole width of the menu. But it looks like its major PITA to make it without image gutter. Gonna take a look into VCL styles overriding on some more rainy day.

Comment: Why did you choose to use VCL styles then?

Comment: I actually don't. It's non-themed win app, without VCL styles.

Comment: Hmm. So why does it have that non-standard colour scheme?

Comment: You can drop `TStandardColorMap` on form and connect it to `TActionMainMenuBar`

Comment: Now when I think of it, VCL styles don't have anything with it, since I don't use them.

Comment: OK, this is the way you might style an app before VCL styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below sample tries to demonstrate what it would take to use your own menu style. It just tries to gain the space from the unused images but you can override any aspect of the drawing, see 'xpactnctrls.pas' for possible implementation.

```
type
  TBarStyle = class(TXPStyleActionBars)
  public
    function GetControlClass(ActionBar: TCustomActionBar;
      AnItem: TActionClientItem): TCustomActionControlClass; override;
  end;

  TMenuStyle = class(TXPStyleMenuItem)
  protected
    procedure CalcLayout; override;
  public
    procedure CalcBounds; override;
  end;

var
  BarStyle: TBarStyle;

function TBarStyle.GetControlClass(ActionBar: TCustomActionBar;
  AnItem: TActionClientItem): TCustomActionControlClass;
begin
  Result := inherited GetControlClass(ActionBar, AnItem);
  if ActionBar is TCustomActionPopupMenu then
    Result := TMenuStyle;
end;

procedure TMenuStyle.CalcLayout;
begin
  inherited;
  GlyphPos := Point(-16, GlyphPos.Y);
end;

procedure TMenuStyle.CalcBounds;
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  inherited;
  R := TextBounds;
  OffsetRect(R, -16, 0);
  TextBounds := R;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ActionMainMenuBar1.ActionManager.Style := BarStyle;
end;

initialization
  BarStyle := TBarStyle.Create;
  RegisterActnBarStyle(BarStyle);
finalization
  UnregisterActnBarStyle(BarStyle);
  BArStyle.Free;
```

Comment: This looks like it may be what I need. Just tested and got some (unsuccessful) results, but atleast I have something to start from. Thanks, gonna get back with info once I try it out more.

Comment: @Marko - Yeah, it doesn't look quite right with only offsetting the rect. The Register/Unregister calls in the above code does not seem to be necessary BTW, they are probably for design time.

Comment: Made it: http://i.imgur.com/mxiLCjb.png looks good, and checkboxes look nice too (I just skip offsetting the text to the left for them). I had to override `DrawGlyph()` and `DrawSeparator()` functions tho, and basically replicate whole code just to edit few lines of it.